# Why PKReveal rightViewController gets nil?

Tags: ios, swift

I have used PKReveal in my application and first time my right menu opens but second time it becomes nil . please tell me what is mistake.
My code to open menu is :

```
 class  func displaySlideMenu(viewController:UIViewController)
{

    if viewController.navigationController?.revealController.focusedController() == viewController.navigationController?.revealController.rightViewController
    {

        APP_DELEGATE.navigationController?.revealController.showViewController(viewController.navigationController?.revealController.frontViewController)

    }else {

        print(viewController.navigationController?.revealController.rightViewController)

        APP_DELEGATE.navigationController?.revealController.showViewController(viewController.navigationController?.revealController.rightViewController)
    }

}
```

For set up of reveal controller code is :

```
let frontPageViewController = FrontPageViewController(nibName:"FrontPageViewController",bundle: nil)
    APP_DELEGATE.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: frontPageViewController)
    let rightMenuViewController = RightMenuViewController(nibName:"RightMenuViewController",bundle: nil)
    APP_DELEGATE.revealController = PKRevealController(frontViewController: APP_DELEGATE.navigationController, rightViewController: rightMenuViewController)

    APP_DELEGATE.window?.rootViewController = APP_DELEGATE.revealController
```

My menu opens first time then if i close and try to open again my view controller is printing nil.